# Whats the name of a BMW iDrive type of encoder?

Tags: switches, components, input, encoder, rotary

I am looking for a component that some people call a 7 way encoder switch.

Basically, if you look at the center piece of the BMW iDrive, its that.

It's a knob looking piece that if you turn to the sides it behaves like a D-Pad. Grabbing it and twisting behaves like a rotary switch. Pushing down makes it a button.

I'm trying to find an electronic component that can do those things.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an iDrive, but it looks like the 6DoF sensor on the 3D Connexion Space Pilot device. Most everyone who uses Altium seriously has at least one of these things- they're complementary with a mouse or trackball.

The cheapest one was only about $75 last time I bought one- the fancier ones are around $400 (the main difference is the presence of an LCD display and programmable keys on the Pro versions).

[image]

"3Dconnexion patented six-degrees-of-freedom (6DoF) sensor"

Here is a [teardown](http://poisonnuke.de/forum/index.php?action=ViewThread&TID=6462) of the SpaceNavigator (cheap version) in German.

They don't have switches, all 6 degrees of freedom are proportional (analog).

Comment: +1. Have you tried [SpaceMouse Wireless](http://www.3dconnexion.com/products/spacemousewireless.html) with Altium? Does it works well? I'm very interesting in buying one..

Comment: Or the [SpaceNavigator](http://www.3dconnexion.com/products/spacenavigator.html)..

Comment: I have the SpaceNavigator (gets used occasionally, especially out of the office) and this one: http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-jioPfvvpnQs/UCjRsThP_cI/AAAAAAAAAFY/Ioe_s7Mng90/s1600/SpacePilot.jpg (wired). The 6DoF knob works the same on either. Works well with Altium and Solidworks (less of an improvement on the latter).